# Azure aks no nodes found

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I created an azure AKS with 3 nodes(Standard DS3 v2 (4 vcpus, 14 GB memory)). I was fiddling with the cluster and created a Deployment with 1000 replicas.After this complete cluster went down.

```
azureuser@saa:~$ k get cs
NAME                 STATUS      MESSAGE                                                                                        ERROR
controller-manager   Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10252/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10252: getsockopt: connection refused   
scheduler            Unhealthy   Get http://127.0.0.1:10251/healthz: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:10251: getsockopt: connection refused   
etcd-0               Healthy     {"health": "true"}
```

From debugging it seems both Scheduler and Controller-manager went down. How to Fix this?

What exactly happened when created a Deployment with 1000 replicas? Should it be taken care by k8s?

Few debugging commands output:

```
  kubectl cluster-info
    Kubernetes master is running at https://cg-games-e5252212.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443
    Heapster is running at https://cg-games-e5252212.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
    KubeDNS is running at https://cg-games-e5252212.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
    kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://cg-games-e5252212.hcp.eastus.azmk8s.io:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy
```

Logs for `kubectl cluster-info dump` @ http://termbin.com/e6wb

```
azureuser@sim:~$ az aks scale -n cg -g cognitive-games -c 4 --verbose
Deployment failed. Correlation ID: 4df797b2-28bf-4c18-a26a-4e341xxxxx. Operation failed with status: 200. Details: Resource state Failed
```

no nodes displayed

```
azureuser@si:~$ k get nodes
No resources found
```

Comment: Hi, As you are using AKS which means Kubernetes master is  managed by Azure. In the above scenario Scheduler and Controller-manager are **not** down. You can see It says *connection refused*.

Comment: you can check further information by using `kubectl get events`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi `kubectl get events` says `No resources found`.

Comment: Hi, Cluster is up. We need to get logs of nodes or whole cluster to diagnose the issues. you can run `kubectl cluster-info`

Comment: @SureshVishnoi updated with required logs

Comment: Hi,  as you can see that you have deployed more than enough pods in the clusters. The scheduler is not able to schedule pods on nodes as it can not find nodes with available resources (CPU, ram). **no nodes available to schedule pods**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks silly but when AKS is created in an RG, surprisingly two RGs are created one with the AKS and another one with some random hash having all the VMS. I've deleted the 2nd RG and the basic AKS stopped working.